# System.Linq.Dynamic: How to guarantee parameter order in Parse function?

Tags: c#, system.linq.dynamic

In the code below I successfully use Microsoft's [System.Linq.Dynamic](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Dynamic/) in C# to evaluate string expressions similar to Javascript `eval()`.  However, I cannot figure out **how to guarantee that parameter names and corresponding values match when calling the new function.**  `"SKU + \" \" + Name"` could return `1234 Cola` just as easily as `Cola 1234`.  I have dozens of parameters.

System.Dynamic.Linq's `Parse` method uses `Dictionary<string,object>` to hold parameters internally which is my problem because Dictionary does not guarantee order like Arrays and Lists.  **I assume because Microsoft chose to use Dictionary that there must be some simple fix to the code below to ensure parameter values match up.**  Code was entered in LinqPad.

Are named parameters possible like `Name: "Cola", SKU: "1234"`? Is there some datatype or technique I could use to guarantee parameter names and values match?  Does this require a change to Microsoft's code to replace Dictionary?

```
var symbols = new Dictionary<String, Object>();         // Cannot change symbols datatype
var paramExp = new List<ParameterExpression>();
var paramVal = new List<String>();

var fields = new Dictionary<String,String>();                              // Sample Data
fields["SKU"] = "1234";
fields["Name"] = "Cola";
fields["Type"] = "Drink";
var expression = "SKU + \" \" + Name";

foreach( var f in fields) {                                           // Setup Parameters
    ParameterExpression x =
        Expression.Parameter(Type.GetType("System.String"), f.Key);
    symbols.Add( f.Key, x);
    paramExp.Add( x);
    paramVal.Add( f.Value);
}

Expression body = System.Linq.Dynamic.DynamicExpression.Parse(  
    Type.GetType("System.String"), expression, symbols);

LambdaExpression e = Expression.Lambda(body, 
    paramExp.ToArray());                                      // Order may not match body

var c = e.Compile();

c.DynamicInvoke(paramVal.ToArray());             // Same here ... possible order mismatch
// c.Dump(); // outputs "1234 Cola"
```

Here are the usings for above and System.Linq.Dynamic:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Linq.Dynamic;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Reflection.Emit;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
```